# How to retry kafka deserialization errors encountered by a batch listener?

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka application which suffers from intermittent deserialisation errors (due to connectivity problems to the host which provides Avro schemas)

I would like to back off and retry serialisation exceptions, but I have not been able to figure out how to set that up.

Here's my test configuration:

```java
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class Configuration {
    @Bean("myContainerFactory")
     public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> createFactory(
             KafkaProperties properties
    ) {
        var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(
                new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(
                        properties.buildConsumerProperties(),
                        new StringDeserializer(),
                        new ErrorHandlingDeserializer(new MyDeserializer())
                )
        );
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(
                ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
        );
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler());
        return factory;
    }

    // this fakes occasional errors which succeed after a retry
    static class MyDeserializer implements Deserializer<String> {
        int retries = 0;
        @Override
        public String deserialize(String topic, byte[] bytes) {
            String s = new String(bytes);
            if (s.contains("7") && retries == 0) {
                retries = 1;
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            retries = 0;
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

and my consumer:

```java
@Component
public class StringListener {
    @KafkaListener(
            topics = {"string-test"},
            groupId = "test",
            batch = "true",
            containerFactory = "myContainerFactory"
    )
    public void listen(List<String> messages, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        for (String s: messages) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
}
```

At present the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` just returns `null`.

Do I need to implement a `failedDeserializationFunction`, or is there a there a simple way to configure the factory so that my deserialiser is called again, after a configurable wait, for some configurable number of times?

Answer (score 0):

I would welcome an answer that does this in an idiomatic spring-boot fashion, but you can simply set a `failedDeserializationFunction` which calls the deserializer again:

```java
        MyDeserializer myDeserializer = new MyDeserializer();
        ErrorHandlingDeserializer<String> errorHandlingDeserializer = 
             new ErrorHandlingDeserializer(myDeserializer);
        errorHandlingDeserializer.setFailedDeserializationFunction(f ->
             myDeserializer.deserialize(f.getTopic(), f.getData())
        );
        factory.setConsumerFactory(
                new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(
                        properties.buildConsumerProperties(),
                        new StringDeserializer(),
                        errorHandlingDeserializer
                )
        );
```

That doesn't limit retries, or do any backoff, that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

`DeserializationException`s are considered fatal by default and are not retried.

You can change that behavior by removing the exception type from the default list of fatal exceptions (on the error handler)...

```java
/**
 * Remove an exception type from the configured list. By default, the following
 * exceptions will not be retried:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link DeserializationException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MessageConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MethodArgumentResolutionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link NoSuchMethodException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ClassCastException}</li>
 * </ul>
 * All others will be retried, unless {@link #defaultFalse()} has been called.
 * @param exceptionType the exception type.
 * @return the classification of the exception if removal was successful;
 * null otherwise.
 * @since 2.8.4
 * @see #addNotRetryableExceptions(Class...)
 * @see #setClassifications(Map, boolean)
 */
@Nullable
public Boolean removeClassification(Class<? extends Exception> exceptionType) {
```

Note, however, that with a batch listener, the failed record is sent to the listener with a `null` payload; you can examine the deserialization exception using `ListenerUtils.getExceptionFromHeader()` (with `SerializationUtils.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER`); then re-throw the exception and the batch will be retried. (Consume `List<Message<String>>` to get access to the header or use `@Header` for an additional parameter.

Correction; the listener utils method requires the `ConsumerRecord`, use `byteArrayToDeserializationException()` instead.

However, the `FallbackBatchErrorHandler` (used if you don't throw a `BatchListenerFailedException` with the record number) did not classify exceptions until recently (all exceptions were retried). This is fixed and will be in the next 2.9.x release in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Added some clarification for batch listeners.